# Where can I find large Android 3.* example?

Tags: android

I am very impressed with the stock Android 3.* Gmail app and I would like to find out how it's done.

The specifics of what I want to learn from the GMAIL app are:

- How the list fragment of the various inbox/folders are styled
- How the interaction beween the inbox/folder and the email list
- How the tapping on the email item will hide the inbox/folders and display the email content, and the animation involved
- How the action bars, context menu and other menus get displayed, controller and event handled.

Do you know any app -- which source is open for ppl to learn -- that come close to the Gmail app?

Comment: You might want to be a bit more specific about what in the Gmail app you wish to see sample source for.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there is no Honeycomb source and the gmail app is closed source which is just pre installed on all official android devices.

There is no way to get the source code or the layouts of the Gmail Application.

My tip: search for an open source application that has similar features/behaviors and check the code there.

Comment: I did google for tablet app from github, but I just want recommendation/pointer from ppl here, just incase you guys know exactly where to find what I am looking for. :-)

Comment: Than be much more specific as @CommonsWare said.